# Unexpected white grid structure from ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I was puzzled by my `ContourPlot` result, which prints some unexpected grid lines. My code is as follows:

```
With[{min = -25, max = 25}, 
 ContourPlot[
   Sin[x]*Cos[x] + 6*Cos[y] + 2 Cos[x]*Cos[y] + 6*Sin[y] + 10 Max[Sin[x], Sin[y]], 
   {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, PlotRange -> {min, max}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"SunsetColors", {min, max}}])
 ]
]
```

The result is shown below. Where do the white lines come from?

[image: contour plot with grid of white lines]

Comment: Due to editting error, the code lost some words. The full code is: With[{min = -25, max = 25}, 
 ContourPlot[
  Sin[x]*Cos[x] + 6*Cos[y] + 2 Cos[x]*Cos[y] + 6*Sin[y] + 
   10 Max[Sin[x], Sin[y]], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, PlotRange -> {min, max}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"SunsetColors", {min, max}}])]]

Comment: I fixed the code and the link. You can always edit your questions yourself using the "Edit" button under it.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marco!

Comment: The gridlines go away if you add `Exclusions -> None` as an option to `ContourPlot`.

Comment: The presence of `Max[Sin[x], Sin[y]]` causes the function to not be smooth and the need to add the `Exclusions -> None`

Comment: Thanks, Marco and Bob, it works. I should try more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not smooth because of the `Max` expression it contains. See for instance one slice of that function at an arbitrary value of $y$:

```
Plot[Max[Sin[x], Sin[y]] /. y -> 0, {x, 0, 25}]
```

[image: plot shows abrupt change in Max]

You can see the structure emerge in 3D as well:

```
ContourPlot[Max[Sin[x], Sin[y]], {x, 0, 25}, {y, 0, 25}]
```

[image: contour plot of the Max function]

Finally, you can remove the `Max` portion of your function to make it smooth and the grid lines will no longer appear.

Comment: Thank you, Marco, the function is continuous, but not smooth. The function has a definite value in the plane. Just curious why MMA prints such white lines?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Exclusions -> None` (the exclusions, = white space, arise from `Max` automatically):

```
With[{min = -25, max = 25}, 
 ContourPlot[
  Sin[x]*Cos[x] + 6*Cos[y] + 2 Cos[x]*Cos[y] + 6*Sin[y] + 
   10 Max[Sin[x], Sin[y]], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, PlotRange -> {min, max}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"SunsetColors", {min, max}}]), 
  Exclusions -> None]]
```

[image]

The following show where the singularities are computed to lie:

```
FunctionSingularities[
 Sin[x]*Cos[x] + 6*Cos[y] + 2 Cos[x]*Cos[y] + 6*Sin[y] + 
  10 Max[Sin[x], Sin[y]], {x, y}]
(*  Sin[x] - Sin[y] == 0  *)
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael,  I learned a lot from you.